# Get Forbidden error when try to access apache vhost in windows

Tags: windows-8, vhosts, apache2.2

I'm trying to setting up a vhost list in apache 2.2 in windows8.
This is my httpd.conf (only what I think is important):

```
Listen 80
LoadModule vhost_alias_module modules/mod_vhost_alias.so
ServerName 127.0.0.1:80
DocumentRoot "D:/Documents/htdocs"
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</Directory>
<Directory D:/Documents/htdocs>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

and this is my httpd-vhosts.conf

```
<Directory D:/Documents/htdocs>
    Require all granted
</Directory>
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "D:/Documents/htdocs/vola.it"
    ServerName local.vola.vola.it
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "D:/Documents/htdocs/vola_newsletter/newsletter.vola.it/public"
    ServerName local.newsletter.vola.it
</VirtualHost>
```

Obviusly I modified my host file:

```
127.0.0.1    local.vola.vola.it
127.0.0.1    local.newsletter.vola.it
```

When I ping both local.vola.vola.it and local.newsletter.vola.it I obtain the resolved IP 127.0.0.1 and ping is good, but when I try to open one of this site on a webclient I always obtain a 403 error Forbidden You don't have permission to access / on this server.

Someone can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved, simply I opened the httpd-vhosts.conf with an editor without Administrator rights, so I thought to modify the file but I modified only cache version, not the real file.

When I opened it in Admin mode, I saw that the changes made aren't in the file.

I edit it again and save in Admin mode, restarted Apache and now all works as aspected.

@mods: Please mark as solved, thanks.